# How to set correct perl path

Tags: perl

I have 2 versions of perl installed. perl v5.18.2 and v5.20.0 . But when I do `perl -v` I get perl v5.18.2.  I don't need v5.18.2 at all. I need v5.20.0. How do I change the path to include v5.20.0 and not v5.18.2?

Here is my `$PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

v5.18.2 is installed at `/usr/bin/perl` and `/usr/bin/perl5.18.2`, and v5.20.0 at `/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the perlbrew documentation:

> switch         Permanently use the specified perl as default

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.20.0
```

If you haven't already, you will need to add `source /root/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to your login script for this to work.

Comment: @love2code, Yes, though you'll need to update the shebang (`#!`) lines of scripts installed with a different `perl`.

Comment: When using `perl-build` with `perlbrew` it is important to install the _Perl_ Version at the right place so that it can be recognized by `perlbrew`: `perl-build 5.10.1 ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1 && perlbrew switch 5.10.1`

Answer (score 1):

The following will add the desired build of Perl to the search path so that it's found first:

```
export PATH="/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin:$PATH"
```

You may add that to your login script to make this change permanent.

---

Note that you'll need to update the shebang (`#!`) lines of scripts installed with a different `perl` to the following:

```
#!/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have *three* copies of perl installed, as neither of the paths you mentioned are in the PATH variable yet your shell still finds one

There's no need for *perlbrew*. All you need to do is set your PATH variable on the command line

```
$ export PATH=/usr/bin/perl5.18.2:$PATH
```

If you want to make that change permanent then add the command to your profile file at `~/.profile`